# Project Information Management Tool

Tags: web-apps, file-management, project-management, document-management

My team an I are wondering if there's a tool (open-source or licensed) from where we can store the information of our projects (such as Description, Completion Status etc.) which will be already written in .pdf or .doc formats and index it using references (ex. show me projects that are not completed or show me projects with contract > X).

This tool must be web based (host-client) so we can host it in one of our machines, not an online provider. If you can achieve this using different methods, please let me know as well.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a basic devops workflow.  MS groups all of yve tools into a product called Azure DevOps, Atlassian (a competitor) splits then into separate (but interconnected)  products.

It sounds like you are looking for the features of Atlassian's JIRA.

These tools do no read from PDF/doc files, you have to create projects and tasks in them, but they will allow you to set up multiple projects,  create tasks, create steps for each task, assign tasks, track progress,  etc...  Atlassian's JIRA is the project planning tool.   For documentation they offer Confluence, which is set up like a wiki for a project.  For file management (version control), their product is called gitlab.  This has all of the standard version control features, such as change tracking and performs basic merges automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the response. We are already using Jira and Gitlab, my definition was bad. We are looking for a software that archives files (.pdf, .xls, .docx) just for storage and indexing, not something super complex. Thank you.